# LINQ get find all with id in list

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out non query way to do return a list of all objects if their ID is in test list. Example below:

```
Hero - table
Columns: id = INT , name = STRING, age = INT, power = INT;

var testList = {1,2,3};
var secondArray = {};

foreach (var id in testList )
{
    // check if ID in database
    var item = db.Hero.ToList().Find(o => o.Id = id);
    if( item != null)
    {
       secondArray.push(item);
    }
}
```

Now i have seen this whole thing done in single line but cannot remember how it was done.

The result i am after is List of all objects containing that have ids 1,2,3.

Comment: var secondArray= db.Hero.Where (h=> testList.Contains(h.Id))

Comment: @OfirWinegarten thats it. So simple, yet brain froze. Put it through and i'll accept it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to use `Contains` on `testList`:

```
var secondArray= db.Hero.Where (h=> testList.Contains(h.Id))
```

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
var result = db.Hero.Where(x => testList.Contains(x.Id));
```

This would hit DB just once instead of 3 times.

Comment: Thanks that was the one, I gave you point since i gave answer to Ofir